# R Optimization of grep of data table

Tags: r, loops, optimization, grepl

I´ve got a series of empty largish data tables. They look like this (but much larger, ~6000 columns, between 1 and 100000 rows):

```
apple = c(NA, NA, NA)
orange = c(NA, NA, NA)
pear = c(NA, NA, NA)
demo <- data.table(apple, orange, pear)
row.names(demo) <- c("pineapples", "blood oranges", "grapes")
```

I am doing pattern matching to see if the row names contain the column names, and then mark the corresponding cells as TRUE/FALSE. I have a loop written that works well, but is extremely slow.

```
for(i in 1:ncol(demo)) {
    demo[, i] <- ifelse(grepl(colnames(demo)[i], 
                                      rownames(demo)), 
                                TRUE, 
                                FALSE)
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to do it in a faster way? It would be possible to use java, but I would prefer to solve it in pure R.

Comment: Have you checked the `demo` dataset?  For `data.table`, you can't assign a row name.

Comment: You could probably vectorize this using `outer` and `stringi`, for instance, `outer(row.names(demo), colnames(demo), stringi::stri_detect_fixed)`

Comment: @akrun you can store row names in `data.table`s attributes. Though it's better to create a column I"d guess.

Comment: Btw, you don't need `ifelse` here, you could do `for(i in 1:ncol(demo)) demo[, i] <- grepl(colnames(demo)[i], rownames(demo), fixed = TRUE)` (note the `fixed = TRUE` for efficiency)

Comment: David Arenburg: That worked great. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

We can create a dataset with `FALSE` values, as the `row.names` are not allowed in 'data.table', create a vector of those names

```
rn <- c("pineapples", "blood oranges", "grapes")
for(j in seq_along(demo)){
    set(demo, i= grep(names(demo)[j], rn), j=j, value = TRUE)
   }
```

#### data

```
 demo <- as.data.table(matrix(FALSE,3,3, 
    dimnames=list(NULL, c('apple', 'orange', 'pear'))))
```

Comment: @docendodiscimus  You are right.  THanks for the comment.